# Is it possibe to do an exclusion in an MX record?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

Is it possible to exclude certain addresses or wild card addresses using an MX record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with an MX record, no. It's strictly inclusive.

That sort of thing is typically done with an [spf](/questions/tagged/spf) record. That DNS record is where you list what is allowed and not allowed to send mail.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is it possible to exclude certain addresses or wild card addresses using an MX record?

A: No.